# Mysql db doesnt save text if its too long

Tags: mysql, database, text

My problem is pretty much decribed with the title! I have this code that inserts data to the db:

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
$pName = $_POST['scriptName'];
$pCode = $_POST['code'];
$group = $_POST['group'];
$descri = $_POST['descr'];
$lang = $_POST['lang'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$updateq = "INSERT INTO code_tb (id, Script_Name, Description, Code, Language, Date) VALUES ('NULL', '$pName','$descri', '$pCode', '$lang', '$date')";
$result=mysql_query($updateq);
echo "$pName . $pCode . $group . $descri . $lang . $date";
?>
```

The `Code` field in my database is of type `text`.

When the code is too long it doesn't  get saved in the db and I am not getting any error at all! If i shorten up the text string it works!

Might this be a stupid beginner mistake?

Comment: What does `DESCRIBE code_tb` give you? Is the problem-field a `VARCHAR`, `TINYTEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT`? How long is *too long*? This page, at the MySQL Reference, might help: [Storage Requirements for String Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html#id834328).

Comment: Is it a TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, or LONGTEXT field?

Comment: its a normal text(changed it even to longtext didnt work) $result gives an empty string out if it doesnt work!

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

here are the limits:

text is 2^16  <--- pretty big.

longtext is 2^32  <--- huge

seems unlikely that you are sending more than a LONGTEXT's gigs of data into an sql statement.

so:

1. find out the exact length that causes the problem.
2. see what's going on in the string at around that length.
3. try running the query in the mysql client.
4. the bug might be something unexpected.